# Azure Mobile App and Security

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I've just setup a new Azure Mobile App (first time using one since the old Mobile Services).

After setting up the app you can use one of the "Quick Start" offerings to create a Xamarin.Forms app that connects to your service and they create a dummy ToDoItem table for you. Then you can download the source for the app which is helpful.

The bit where I'm left scratching my head is that previously with the Mobile Services you would have your Mobile Services URL and an API key that was to stay secret (how secret you can keep this is open to debate as at the end of the day it's in your code and is probably possible for someone to reverse engineer the APK or whatever and get it)... BUT with the new Mobile App service there doesn't seem to be any notion of this secret API key. I've hunted around the sample app source and can only find the URL for the app service and nothing else.

So my question is, what's to stop someone else using my Mobile App service URL and reading/writing to (or worse, deleting from) my SQL Server tables?

Perhaps I'm missing something... If anyone can shed any light on the subject that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application key was dropped as a security mechanism as it gave a false sense of security. As you mention, there is nothing to stop people from obtaining the key through reverse engineering the app or capturing network traffic - in some ways it is worse than no security at all!

We highly recommend you set up your tables to only allow authenticated access. Using the social media identity providers don't give you any role based access control, but with Azure Active Directory, you can set up groups fairly easily.

You can find some basic information and tutorials (Xamarin.Forms is included) at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-auth/. There is also a wealth of information on Mobile Apps in general at https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Am I right in thinking though that to login/authenticate with AAD the user will be forwarded to a Microsoft login web view first? I'd rather handle registration myself so users can sign up with a native registration page in-app and then have some way of authenticating requests to the Mobile Service after they've registered and logged in.

Comment: In some ways it's probably easier to just code using HTTP GET/POST requests to my own API before saving to Azure and that way I can ensure only authenticated users are accessing the Azure SQL Server tables (and only accessing what they're entitled to).

Comment: You may want to look at custom authentication, for example, a simple username / password authentication setup. Check out the sample at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples/custom-authentication. There is also a guide to using auth0 at https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/

Comment: Thanks will do, very helpful.